# Enable user to draw a line on the form in a WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

How can I enable the user to draw a line in a form?

Using the left mouse button to draw and the right mouse button to erase.

Comment: Check sample code in this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/c8e09147-dfea-4afa-8006-7c87c7967fe5

Answer (score 1):

Example that draws the line and uses the appropiate place for paint:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                points.Add(e.Location);

                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (points.Count > 2)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```

The ToArray() is not very nice when the list gets long though.

Answer (score 0):

Not that complicated, a quick example... I have not included the checks here.

```
    Graphics g = null; // initialize in Form_Load with this.CreateGraphics()
    Point lastPoint;

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        lastPoint = e.Location;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, lastPoint, e.Location);
            lastPoint = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

The above is an example to show how one can draw on a Form. Ideally, you should put all the line coordinates in a collection and draw that using DrawLines(). Then use the Graphics::DrawLines() in the Form::OnPaint. When the right mouse is clicked, just clear the point collection and force a redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you may want to contain all the drawing/erasing action within a specific control and manage its redraw/invalidation status coherently but A9S6's answer will surely get you started and enjoy some GDI+ drawing ;)