# Draw a line which follows the mouse

Tags: vb.net, graphics, line

I want to load a picture (PNG, JPG, Bitmap) and then, I want to draw a line onto my picture.

At the moment I use a PictureBox to load my picture:

Here is the MouseMove part of my Code:

```
If mClickOne = True Then
    If Not mSetDrawPictureAlready Then
        g = Graphics.FromImage(picFormular.Image)
        mRawPicture = picFormular.Image
            mSetDrawPictureAlready = True
    End If
    If mChoosenDrawFunction = DrawFunction.Ausrichten Then
        g.Clear(Color.Transparent)
        g.DrawImage(mRawPicture, picFormular.Location)
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, New Point(mClickOnePosX, mClickOnePosY), New Point(e.X, e.Y))
        picFormular.Refresh()
    ElseIf mChoosenDrawFunction = DrawFunction.FeldMakieren Then
        'Missing Code
    Else
        'Nothing
    End If
End If
```

On this I can draw a line with a click on PointOne and a click on PointTwo, but my picture is disappearing if the MouseMove event is called, so I draw my line on a clean surface.

On my first try to fix the problem I got another problem. If I draw my line, my old line didn't disappear. So, my complete surface was full with thousands of lines.

Anyone of you know how to fix my problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i enable user to draw line on the form in a WinForms application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442265/how-can-i-enable-user-to-draw-line-on-the-form-in-a-winforms-application)

Comment: Thank You, The link in comments of your link was exactly what i was looking for